# Remove a class from a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my first question on stack overflow - so hello everybody!

I'm attempting to use dynamic dropdowns to display text within a div. I've managed to set up the dynamic dropdowns so that the second list is populated based on what option is selected in the first list.

However what I want to do now is display the text within a div below this form but I'm struggling to figure out how to do this. I've hidden the text that is currently in the div by assigning a class called 'hide' using CSS "display:none".

```
<div class="hide">
<h2>Camden Town Library - Monday</h2>
<p>
  Camden Town Monday opening hours
</p>
```

```
.hide {display: none;}
```

Where I'm getting stuck is removing this class with jQuery. I know that I probably need to use something like removeClass('hide') when an option is selected but I'm not sure how to actually do that. How do I know which option is selected?

```
if($(lib).val() == "Camden" && $(day).val() == "Monday") { removeClass('hide') }
```

I know I also need to use data-target but not sure how to implement this.

Here is my work so far: http://codepen.io/smifaye/pen/woYWdO

Any help would be much appreciated.

smifaye

Comment: [Google is your friend](https://www.google.com/search?q=remove+a+class+with+jQuery)

Comment: give you div a ID so you can call him with $(#). example of removing:
$("#target").removeClass("hide");

Comment: Following N. Smeding `<div id="Camden-Monday" class="hide">
<h2>Camden Town Library - Monday</h2>
<p>
  Camden Town Monday opening hours
</p>` and `$("#"+ $(lib).val() + "-" + $(day).val()).removeClass('hide')`

Comment: why not simply document.getElementsByClassName('hide').forEach((el)=>{el.style.display="block"}); ?

Comment: @Jonasw Because (1 That doesn't work (`getElementsByClassName` returns a [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), not an Array.) (2 That will show all hidden items regardless of their value, while the OP wants to show ones with certain values, and (3 random arrow function?

Comment: @Jacob Gray: yes, yes,his question sounds good, so i think he can figure out the selection part alone, and yes i like arrow functions...

Comment: @Jonasw arrow functions are nice to use with Nodejs because of their lexical scoping, but can't really be used on the frontend yet, because they aren't supported in IE 11

Comment: @Jacob Gray Well, i dont care about the people using IE, they should definitly get another browser...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the change event you can use

```
$(document).on('change', 'select', function(){
  var lib = $('select[name="lib"]').val();
  var day = $('select[name="day"]').val();
  $('div[data-library]').addClass('hide');
  $('div[data-library="'+lib+'"][data-day="'+day+'"]').removeClass('hide');
});
```

Then on each of the divs add the data-day="monday" and data-library="camden" that it applies to.

You also wont need to add the options using javascript, check out my codepen to see it all working and clean.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NbOZpo?editors=1111

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NbOZpo?editors=1111



Ive updated your codepen to set you on the right track

Comment: Ah @Craig thank you so much! The JS file is now a lot lot smaller also

Comment: Awesome, you're welcome! Yeah its nice to have a clean javascript file that does a lot with only a few lines!

Answer (score 0):

A simple sollution is to handle it on `$day` dropdown `change` event, using the `:eq(index)` [jquery function](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) 
like this

```
$day.change(function() {    
    if($library.val() == "Camden" && $day.val() == "Monday") {
      $('.hide').eq( 0 ).removeClass('hide');
    }
});
```

Do the same for the other library and day choises but replace the '0' with the right index for each case. **Check it out, chose Camden and Monday, then Thuesday:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $library = $("select[name='lib']");
  $day = $("select[name='day']");

  $library.change(function() {

    if ($(this).val() == "Camden") {
      $("select[name='day'] option").remove();
      $("<option>Select day</option>").appendTo($day);
      $("<option>Monday</option>").appendTo($day);
      $("<option>Tuesday</option>").appendTo($day);
      $("<option>Wednesday</option>").appendTo($day);
      $("<option>Thursday</option>").appendTo($day);
      $("<option>Friday</option>").appendTo($day);
      $("<option>Saturday</option>").appendTo($day);
      $("<option>Sunday</option>").appendTo($day);
    }

    if ($(this).val() == "Holborn") {
      $("select[name='day'] option").remove();
      $("<option>Select day</option>").appendTo($day);
      $("<option>Monday</option>").appendTo($day);
      $("<option>Tuesday</option>").appendTo($day);
      $("<option>Wednesday</option>").appendTo($day);
      $("<option>Thursday</option>").appendTo($day);
      $("<option>Friday</option>").appendTo($day);
      $("<option>Saturday</option>").appendTo($day);
      $("<option>Sunday</option>").appendTo($day);
    }

    if ($(this).val() == "Please select from above") {
      $("select[name='day'] option").remove();
      $("<option>Not applicable</option>").appendTo($day);
    }
  });
  
  
  $day.change(function() {    
    $('.panel>div').addClass('hide');//Hide ALL
    if($library.val() == "Camden" && $day.val() == "Monday") {
      $('.hide').eq( 0 ).removeClass('hide');
    }
    else if($library.val() == "Camden" && $day.val() == "Tuesday") {
      $('.hide').eq( 1 ).removeClass('hide');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.searchbox {
  border: 2px solid #00019F;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 305px;
}

button {
  border: 2px solid #00019F;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #CCCCCC;
  color: #00019F;
  width: 150px;
  height: 36px;
}

button:hover, button:focus {
  border: 2px solid #FF9900;
  outline: none;
  background: #EFEFEF;
}

select {
  border: 2px solid #6C6C6C;
  background: white;
  height: 34px;
  width: 280px;
}

select:focus {
  border: 2px solid #FF9900;
  outline: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
  .searchbox {
    width: 260px;
  }
  select {
    width: 235px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://www.camden.gov.uk/themes/published-themedir/camden-bremen/styles/public.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://www.camden.gov.uk/themes/published-themedir/camden-bremen/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="library" style="padding-bottom:10px;">Select the Library and day from the lists below to see opening hours:</div>
<div class="searchbox">
  <div style="border-bottom-left-radius: 10px; background-color: #00019F;">
    <h3 style="margin: 0px; padding: 10px; color: white;">Library opening hours</h3>
  </div>

  <form>
    <div class="heading" style="padding: 10px;">
      <b>Library:</b>
      <select name="lib">
    <option>Please select</option>
    <option>Camden</option>
    <option>Holborn</option>
   </select>
    </div>
    <div style="padding: 10px;">
      <b>Day of the week:</b>
      <select name="day">
    <option>Please select from above</option>
   </select>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="panel">
  <div class="hide">
    <h2>Camden Town Library - Monday</h2>
    <p>
      Camden Town Monday opening hours
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="hide">
    <h2>Camden Town Library - Tuesday</h2>
    <p>
      Camden Town Tuesday opening hours
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="hide">
    <h2>Camden Town Library - Wednesday</h2>
    <p>
      Camden Town Wednesday opening hours
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="hide">
    <h2>Camden Town Library - Thursday</h2>
    <p>
      Camden Town Thursday opening hours
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="hide">
    <h2>Camden Town Library - Friday</h2>
    <p>
      Camden Town Friday opening hours
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="hide">
    <h2>Camden Town Library - Saturday</h2>
    <p>
      Camden Town Saturday opening hours
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="hide">
    <h2>Camden Town Library - Sunday</h2>
    <p>
      Camden Town Sunday opening hours
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="hide">
    <h2>Holborn Library - Monday</h2>
    <p>
      Holborn Monday opening hours
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="hide">
    <h2>Holborn Library - Tuesday</h2>
    <p>
      Holborn Tuesday opening hours
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="hide">
    <h2>Holborn Library - Wednesday</h2>
    <p>
      Holborn Wednesday opening hours
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="hide">
    <h2>Holborn Library - Thursday</h2>
    <p>
      Holborn Thursday opening hours
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="hide">
    <h2>Holborn Library - Friday</h2>
    <p>
      Holborn Friday opening hours
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="hide">
    <h2>Holborn Library - Saturday</h2>
    <p>
      Holborn Saturday opening hours
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="hide">
    <h2>Holborn Library - Sunday</h2>
    <p>
      Holborn Sunday opening hours
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<div class="hide anotherName">`

```
if($(lib).val() == "Camden" && $(day).val() == "Monday") {
     $(".anotherName").removeClass("hide")
}
```

or

`<div id="hideIt" class="hide">`

```
if($(lib).val() == "Camden" && $(day).val() == "Monday") {
     $("#hideIt").removeClass("hide")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the toggleClass function using jQuery. Here you can see the example.

```
<button type="submit">toggle div</button>
<p>This is the content to be hide.</p>
button{
    background: #d81c1c;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #d81c1c;
    padding: 6px 15px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
.hide{
    display: none;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').on('click', function(){
        $('p').toggleClass('hide');
    })
})
```

Here is my codepen

http://codepen.io/ektad/pen/QGJLda